# Confused About Relationships and HQL Queries in CF ORM

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

For the sake of simplicity, assume I have two entities configured as follows:

**Topic.cfc**

```
/**
 * @accessors true
 * @persistent true
 */
component {

    /**
     * @fieldtype id
     * @generator uuid
     * @sqltype varchar(35)
     */
    property topicID;

    /**
     * @type array
     * @fieldtype one-to-many
     * @cfc Response
     * @fkcolumn topicID
     * @singularname response
     */
    property responses;
}
```

**Response.cfc**

```
/**
 * @accessors true
 * @persistent true
 */
component {

    /**
     * @fieldtype id
     * @generator uuid
     * @sqltype varchar(35)
     */
    property responseID;

    /**
     * @type date
     * @ormtype timestamp
     */
    property responseTime;
}
```

I need to run a HQL query (or not, you tell me...) that will return all responses for a specified topic during a specified date range.

My query currently looks like this:

```
var params = {
    'start' = startDate,
    'end' = endDate,
    'topicID' = topicID
};
var responses = ormExecuteQuery('
    from Response
    where responseTime >= :start
    and responseTime <= :end
    and Topic.topicID = :topicID
', params );
```

It returns the following error: `could not resolve property: Topic of: Response [ from Response as r where r.responseTime >= :start and r.responseTime <= :end and r.Topic.topicID = :topicID ]`

I've tried joining:

```
from Response as r
join r.Topic as t
...
```

But that results in the same error. Not really sure where to go from here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query, as written, assumes there is a relationship from Response to Topic - which, based on your code, there is not.

Pretty sure that if you add that relationship to Response, the query will work.

Comment: Ah, too easy! I just switched around the query a little: `from Topic as t join t.responses r where r.responseTime >= :start and r>responseTime <= :end and t.topicID = :topicID`. Thanks, Scott!